# Nodejs, bodyParser. req,res, works for login and register, but not profile update.req variables undefiend

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, body-parser

I am using SnowSQL as the Database, and making an a user profile functionality. When I entry my user information username, password, firstname, lastname, it all comes back as undefined.

My app.js code:

```
 var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
 const express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, user = require('./routes/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');
//const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

 let bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
    account: '***********',  
   username: '***********',
   password: '***********', //creds commented out for security reasons. 
  database: '***********'
       }
   );

connection.connect( 
     function(err, conn) {
     if (err) {
         console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
       } 
      else {
         console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake test account.');
          // Optional: store the connection ID.
         connection_ID = conn.getId();
         }
     }
      );

//global.db = connection;

// all environments
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(session({
           secret: 'keyboard cat',
           resave: false,
           saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
            }))

   // development only

      app.get('/', routes.index);//call for main index page
      app.get('/signup', user.signup);//call for signup page
     app.post('/signup', user.signup);//call for signup post 
     app.get('/reset', user.reset);//call for signup page
     app.post('/reset', user.reset);//call for signup page
     app.post('/forgot', user.forgot);//call for signup post 
     app.get('/forgot', user.forgot);//call for signup post 
     app.get('/login', routes.index);//call for login page
     app.post('/login', user.login);//call for login post
     app.get('/home/dashboard', user.dashboard);//call for dashboard page after login
     app.get('/home/logout', user.logout);//call for logout
     app.get('/home/profile',user.profile);//to render users profile
     app.post('/home/profile',user.editprofile);//to render users profile
     app.get('/verification/',user.verify);

//Middleware
app.listen(8080)
```

User.js edit profile function:

```
   exports.editprofile = function (req, res) {
   var userId = req.session.userId;
   if (req.method == "POST") {  //using res to initialize my accounts table variables. 
    // var post = req.session;
     var userId = '2';
     var post = req.body;
     var name = post.user_name;
     var pass = post.password;
     var fname = post.first_name;
     var lname = post.last_name;
     var email = post.email;

       console.log(name, pass, fname, lname); //Coming out as undefined
         if (userId == null) {
         res.redirect("/login");
        return;
      }
   connection.execute({
     sqlText: "UPDATE TEST.PUBLIC.ACCOUNTS SET FIRST_NAME =" + "'" +fname+ "'" + ", LAST_NAME = " 
      + "'" + lname+ "'" + ", USER_NAME = " + "'" + name + "'" + ", PASSWORD = " + "'" + pass + "'" + 
     " WHERE EMAIL = 'fakemeail@gmail.com'",
       // UPDATE TEST.PUBLIC.ACCOUNTS SET FIRST_NAME = 'John', LAST_NAME = 'Smith', USER_NAME = 
       'Jsmith365', PASSWORD = '3Hotdogs' WHERE EMAIL = 'fakemeail@gmail.com';
         complete: function (err, stmt, row) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
         }
         else {
            console.log('Sucessfully updated profile');
            res.redirect('/home/dashboard');
         }
      }
     });
    } else {
     res.redirect('/home/dashboard');
   }
   };
```

My Database connection works fine. That works because the values change to undefined when I go to snowflake database and shows undefined  on the frontend. It seems the body parsers doesn't know what values I'm talking about so it is undefined. On top of that, the exacpt code to intionalize my varibles works for login and register on the frontend and database. I feel like I am missing something. Is it in my app.js? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are including the `content-type` headers in the request
Example:

- for Json data include `Content-Type: application/json` header
- for x-www-form-urlencoded include `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header

Comment: How do I add these headers?

Comment: How do I check these?

Comment: If you are using Postman to test the api then you can include the headers there.
If you are sending an ajax request from browser then you can add the header
like in the example below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch